# Mongodb structure operation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Another day. Another Mongodb query.

I wish to create the following structure in once of my collections:

`amitverma` is the user and the nested object is message's UTC timestamp. I want to push messages in the following structure.

```
{
    "username" : "macbook",
    "messages" : {
        "amitverma" : {
            "1383321755" : {
                "to" : "macbook",
                "message" : "hi.",
                "sender" : "amitverma",
            },
            "1383321712" : {
                "to" : "macbook",
                "message" : "hi.",
                "sender" : "amitverma",
            }
        }
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("5273d09ab743db7a5f000001")
}
```

I cant use $push or $addToSet as it isnt an array. Or can I?

Also, I have the following code right now:

```
var pushNotification = {};
    var addon = {};
    var anotheraddon = {};
    var utcTime = arrayOps.encodeTime();

    addon[data.sender] = [];
    anotheraddon[utcTime] = data;
    addon[data.sender].push(anotheraddon);

    // var a = pushNotification;
    // a.push(anotheraddon);
    // console.log(pushNotification);

    pushNotification['messages'] = {}
    pushNotification['messages'][data.sender] = [];
    pushNotification['messages'][data.sender] = data;

    var a = 'messages.' + data.sender + '.$';


    console.log('push object');
    console.log(pushNotification);
    co_notifications.update(
        {'username': data.to}, 
        { $addToSet: pushNotification}, function(err, docs){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(docs);
            if (docs == 0){
                co_notifications.insert(
                    {'username': data.to, 'messages': addon}, function(er, doc){
                });
            }
        },
        {upsert: true}
    );
```

Excuse the garbage code. The above code results in this structure:

```
{
    "username" : "macbook",
    "messages" : {
        "amitverma" : [
            {
                "1383321755" : {
                    "to" : "macbook",
                    "message" : "hi.",
                    "sender" : "amitverma",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("5273d09ab743db7a5f000001")
}
```

which isn't exactly what I desire.

Is there a way I can create the structure I want and also read and update from the same easily? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want such structure for messages? I'd better save sender name and date in fields within `message` object and save objects in array.

Comment: then how would I append more data inside the sender's object?

Comment: I believe you store data about senders in other collection (or in this `user` object), and in `messages` you keep only facts that user received message from somebody. Anyway you will be able to add extra data in message objects on par with sender name.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert additional elements of the form you outlined above to
an existing document by using the following update:

```
info = {"to": "...", "message": "...",  "sender": "..."}
c.update({}, {$set: {'messages.amitverma.1111111111': info}})
```

After executing this update on your example document the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5273d09ab743db7a5f000001"),
    "messages" : {
        "amitverma" : {
            "1111111111" : {
                "to" : "...",
                "message" : "...",
                "sender" : "..."
            },
            "1383321712" : {
                "to" : "macbook",
                "message" : "hi.",
                "sender" : "amitverma"
            },
            "1383321755" : {
                "to" : "macbook",
                "message" : "hi.",
                "sender" : "amitverma"
            }
        }
    },
    "username" : "macbook"
}
```

You don't say what kind of queries you want to do, but here's an
example that shows the kind of thing you might do. This query finds a
document with a give username, and uses a projection to return only a
specific subset of the document, in this example the element that we just
added:

```
c.findOne({username:'macbook'}, {'messages.amitverma.1111111111':1})
```

This query produces the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5273d09ab743db7a5f000001"),
    "messages" : {
        "amitverma" : {
            "1111111111" : {
                "to" : "...",
                "message" : "...",
                "sender" : "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Bruce

Comment: `{messages.amitverma.111111111} ` - the thing is amitverma is a variable.. $addToSet doesnt seem to play nice with variables in queries. are you sure this would work?

Comment: You can construct the string 'messages.amitverma.1111111111' from a variable before passing it to the query, for example: s = 'messages.' + v + '.1111111111'. Does that help?

Comment: no it doesnt actually. it would add the variable `s` as the key instead of using that as the path